# Why is IO.Path.GetTempPath() appending a folder to TMP environmental variable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, environment-variables

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx), GetTempPath is supposed to return the environmental variable TMP, TEMP, USERPROFILE, or the Windows Directory successively if the previous is undefined.  On a system I was looking at today, GetTempPath was returning "%TMP%\8\" which didn't exist and was causing a DirectoryNotFound exception when attempting to copy a file.  The TMP environmental variable did not contain the "\8\" directory. It appears that other user profiles on the same system had other numbered directories (9,17, etc) inside TMP as well.

Anyone have any idea why that was taking place?

Here is the code, I verified that IO.Path.GetFileName is not returning anything weird:

```
Dim sLocalPath As String
sLocalPath = IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath, IO.Path.GetFileName(RemotePath))
```

We were able to fix on that system by simply re-creating the folder, and have modified our code to create the folder if it does not exist. No longer a critical issue but seemed weird enough to ask about, and I want to make sure our fix is headed the right direction.

Comment: Raymond Chen's [Why does the name of my TEMP directory keep changing?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110125-00/?p=11673): "... it opens C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\1, C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\2, and so on. Each time the user logs off and back on, the number increments ..."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks a bunch.  I never connected it to RDP sessions, that seems to be the exact cause.

Comment: Here is an updated link to [Why Does the name of my TEMP directory keep changing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110125-00/?p=11673)
TLDR: accessing the computer from remote desktop causes this. It can be turned off.